# Invalid or unexpected token in WebAssembly

Tags: webassembly, rust-rocket

I am trying to run a WebAssembly program (written in Rust, the example-program from https://rustwasm.github.io/book/game-of-life/hello-world.html) with Rocket. The WebAssembly is compiled with wasm-pack and using the wasm_bindgen. The wasm binary is represented as `content::JavaScript<Vec<u8>>` in Rocket and it seems like this is a 'working' solution. The binary is 'correctly' fetched, however Chrome prints a Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token. Is this due to the representation as `content::JavaScript<Vec<u8>>` that there is an error during fetching (although the send bytes match the ones in the wasm file) or is the bug elsewhere?

I hope someone can explane me why there is a SyntaxError in a generated binary file.

Answer (score 1):

Ok now i think i know what went wrong:
The js file generated from the wasm-pack trys to load the WebAssembly as module. The module needts to have a Javascript mime otherwise it will fail (that is why i tried to send the wasm file as `content::JavaScript<Vec<u8>>`), but apparently loading a wasm as modul is not supported (correct me if i am wrong) so of course it will find an invalid token in a binary file because it trys to interpret it as plain javascript. What i actually use now is the `Option<NamedFile>` type from Rocket witch has a `application/wasm` mime.
I needed to change the generated js file a bit: the WebAssembly is initialized with `WebAssembly.instatiateStreaming(fetch(...), importObjects)`, the module import should then be removed. The `importObjects` was a little tricky too, because passing strigns to WebAssembly is a little inconvenient. For an alert function that can be called from WebAssembly the `importObjects` looked like this:
`let importObjects = {'./wasm_test': { __wbg_alert_3d9cbee15c16469e: __wbg_alert_3d9cbee15c16469e }};`.
The names are from the wasm binary: `(import "./wasm_test" "__wbg_alert_3d9cbee15c16469e" (func $__wbg_alert_3d9cbee15c16469e (type $t0)))`
The function `__wbg_alert_3d9cbee15c16469e` is generated by the wasm-pack. The last thing to change is the object that got originally imported via a `import` statement. I have now a variable that has the content from `obj.instance.exports` which is set in the then statement from the `WebAssembly.instatiateStreaming(fetch(...), importObjects).then(obj => {
    wasm = obj.instance.exports;
})`
With these changes it worked for me (sending and reading strings to/from WebAssembly)

Comment: Do you have a link to a github repository of your complete code that works with Rocket and wasm and the example from the book?

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Ben's answer. The `.wasm` file is sent with an `application/javascript` mime thus the browser is trying to execute it as javascript. to send it with an `application/wasm` mime make sure your response is of type `Option<rocket::response::NamedFile>`.

Here's an example:

```
#[get("/pkg/<file..>")]
fn get_pkg(file : PathBuf) -> Option<rocket::response::NamedFile> {
   NamedFile::open(Path::new("client/pkg/").join(file)).ok()
}
```

---

Regarding the second issue - turns out rather than manually editing the javascript generated by `wasm-pack build` you can actually ask `wasm-pack` to generate javascript that can run in the browser and load your wasm. simply do 
`wasm-pack build --target web`.

All there is left to do is add something like this on your side:

```
<script type="module">
  import init from './pkg/client.js'; //client.js is the file generated by wasm
  async function run() {
    await init();
  }
  run();
</script>
```